# Transfer files from GCS bucket to Webdav server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP and was wondering whther what I am trying to achieve is possible.

I have a dataflow job which creates a csv file on a daile basis and stores it to GCS bcket. This file is overwritten everyday.

What I want to do is when a file is created or overwritten then automaically transfer the file to a WebDav server. I need to scheduke this process on a daily basis.

Is this possibnle to set up within GCS?

Any advice is apprecaited.

i have been looking at cloud file transfers and data transfer but its not correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Functions to trigger a transfer of the file whenever it is created or overwritten in the GCS bucket.According to the  [Cloud Storage Triggers Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-calling-storage-node8up)

> In Cloud Functions, a Cloud Storage trigger enables a function to be
> called in response to changes in Cloud Storage. When you specify a
> Cloud Storage trigger for a function, you choose an event type and
> specify a Cloud Storage bucket. Your function will be called whenever
> a change occurs on an object (file) within the specified bucket.
>
> - object.finalize - Triggered when a new object is created, or an    existing object is overwritten and a new generation of that object is
>   created.

Check this [Cloud Storage function tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) for an example of writing, deploying, and calling a function with a Cloud Storage trigger.